# What distance apart should metal stud securing brackets be placed?

Tags: drywall, studs

I have hired a contractor to line the walls of an old apartment with metal stud and drywall as the walls are very uneven. The drywall is up but the walls have quite a lot of give in them, if I push against them with my hand the wall wobbles a little, is this acceptable?  I would expect there to be no give at all.
I suspect that this is because the contractor has not secured the stud to the wall with enough mounting brackets, either to save time or money. Is there a standard spacing for securing stud to the wall, my walls are approx 3 metres high and the contractor has used 1 bracket per stud, in some cases there seems to be no bracket, the stud is just screwed at the top and bottom.
Thanks a lot, I can't afford to have this fixed afterwards so need to make sure this guy does it right before it is plastered.

Comment: I would ask for a picture of the installed studs but if they are already covered with the drywall there should not be much to see.  I would think one issue is the uneven walls make it hard to secure each and every stud tight to the wall as this would possibly draw the new stud wall in to unevenness.

Comment: Metal studs do feel "wobbly" compared to wood when free standing. Once the sheetrock is screwed in place it will feel normal.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the studs would be fastened to the wall with clips or L metal.
Spacing would be 24 inches vertical & 48 inches Horizontally.
Metal studs have a punch out for bridging typical 4' 6" vertical for cold rolled channel to be in stalled some bridging require clips screw attached and others just snap in place depending on the manufacture.
You also need to check on the Seismic rating as you stated plaster was being installed.

Answer (score 0):

Normally finished walls with metal studs feel just as solid as wood framed.  They are supposedly stronger than wood framed, not sure I buy that, but I am confident they are strong enough.

As for the requirement of wall brackets - without knowing more about how the walls are supported you couldn't say home many are required.  After all it's very possible to construct metal framed partition walls that are attached only to each other and the floor that are perfectly sturdy and rigid.